# Check whether data in cell of datagridview is null

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net, datagridview

My DataGridView is bound to a database query result via a `SqlDataReader`, and when I test a cell value for `null`, I'm getting unexpected results.

My code is something like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
     "Data Source = .;Initial Catalog = SAHS;integrated security = true");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(
    "select  Status from vw_stdtfeedetail 
     where Std= 6  and Div ='B' and name='bbkk' and mnthname ='June'", con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dr;
dataGridView3.DataSource = bs;
this.monthFeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.sAHSDataSet4.MonthFee);
if (dataGridView3.CurrentCell.Value == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Pending");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already Paid");
}
```

I'm getting output **Already Paid** even though the value from database is **null**.

Comment: when you debug, what does the value show as?

Comment: @StingyJack - This is the exact opposite of what the OP is assuming. He is assuming NULL to mean not paid. It could be a column indicating the date that something was paid, therefore NULL is the perfect way to indicate that there is no date paid.

Comment: Yep, I've clearly got a case of the mondays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`

```
if (dataGridView3.CurrentCell.Value == DBNull.Value)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Pending");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already Paid");
}
```

Comment: @HMcompfreak If this is the correct answer please mark it as the correct answer to remove it from the "Unanswered" questions pile. Cheers.